# Firebase Analytics event app_clear_data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

What data included in `app_clear_data`?, is it mean that shared preferences also cleared?

Didn't found any information in the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en)

> when the user resets/clears the app data, removing all settings and sign-in data